# Sencha Touch default item selection in list

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

by default how to select first item in list, without tapping it? below is the my view.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'testlist',
    config: {
        flex: 1,
        enableSelection: true,
        itemTpl: '{item}',
        data: [
            {item: 'item-1'},
            {item: 'item-2'},
            {item: 'item-3'},
            {item: 'item-4'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.List has two methods that will help you:

```
list.select( record, keepExisting, surpessEvent );
list.selectRange( startRecordIndex, endRecordIndex, keepExisting );
```

In your case you can you use `list.selectRange( 1, 1, false );` to select the second data record.